# How to shorthand following statement

Tags: php, coding-style, conditional-operator

I'm trying to shorthand the following if else statement. But getting errors.

```
if ($jobs->due_out == null) {
 return ('N/A');
} else {
 return date(self::DATETIME, strtotime($jobs->due_out));
}
```

This is what i tried so far:

```
return 'N/A' ? $jobs->due_out == null : date(self::DATETIME, strtotime($jobs->due_out);
```

This is in Php. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement is slightly the wrong way round, you need the condition first...

```
return ($jobs->due_out == null) ? 'N/A' : date(self::DATETIME, strtotime($jobs->due_out));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried this method too. But missing the start and end brackets. That's why I got an error. Thank you very much  my friend.

Comment: You don't even need the `()` around the condition.